# Arquivo css específico para cada página wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Estou fazendo algumas páginas customizadas em um template de wordpress e gostaria de colocar um stylesheet de css em cada uma direto na header. Existe alguma forma de fazer isso ? Tentei pegar o título da página e não consegui. Apenas do post.

Comment: get_the_title não pegou o titulo da pagina?

Comment: Não pegou, mas talvez seja porque não tem nenhum post na pagina

Comment: Isso será meio trabalhoso, porque há a necessidade de fazer um css para cada página?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O jeito correto de se adicionar CSS a um site WordPress é usando [`wp_enqueue_style`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style). Vocẽ pode fazer assim no seu `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'meu_css' );
function meu_css() {
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'nome-do-css',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/caminho/do/arquivo.css',
        array(), // defina dependências aqui (opcional)
        '1.0', // versão do seu tema (opcional)
    );
}
```

Esse hook roda depois das consultas então é possível usar [Conditional Tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) ou qualquer outra função do WP para determinar em qual página estamos. Por exemplo, se o CSS é só para páginas e o arquivo do css tem o slug da página, isso aqui deve fazer o que você precisa:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'meu_css' );
function meu_css() {
    global $post;

    if( is_page() ) { // somente se for uma página
        wp_enqueue_style(
            'nome-personalizado',
            get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/' . $post->post_name . '.css',
            array(), // defina dependências aqui (opcional)
            '1.0', // versão do seu tema (opcional)
        );
    }
}
```

Numa página chamada Hello World, com slug `hello-world` o exemplo acima vai carregar o arquivo `http://seusite.com/wp-content/themes/seutema/css/hello-world.css`